# convert string table into dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, response

I have one table in the string and I want to convert it into a dictionary of dictionaries. How can I do it?

I have tried to convert string into list by split but I didn't get it.

```py
dbresponse = '''
 key    | account_guid | activation_code | external_id | location
--------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------
    1.1 |         null |    1000005-1212 |           1 | 10.0.9.16
    1.4 |         null |    500000551212 |           5 | 10.0.9.16
    1.6 |         null |    700000551212 |           7 | 10.0.9.16
    1.5 |         null |    400000551212 |           4 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1992 |         null |    157990235555 |   exr498680 | 10.0.9.16
    1.3 |         null |    200000551212 |           2 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2052 |         null |    423838550909 |   exr084213 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2152 |         null |    563626550909 |   exr350970 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1534 |         null |    835749550909 |   exr245191 | 10.0.9.16
  1.161 |         null |    547489550909 |   exr413464 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1955 |         null |    961459478950 |   exr874895 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1812 |         null |    535999550909 |   exr991462 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2153 |         null |    525874550909 |   exr446117 | 10.0.9.16
    1.2 |         null |    300000551212 |           3 | 10.0.9.16
  1.206 |         null |    997141550909 |   exr987098 | 10.0.9.16
  1.101 |         null |    870827550909 |   exr867333 | 10.0.9.16
  1.302 |         null |    938271123405 |   exr989961 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1795 |         null |    360276365614 |   exr498651 | 10.0.9.16
  1.855 |         null |    751409654321 |   exr130325 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1232 |         null |    397846550909 |   exr557906 | 10.0.9.16
    1.8 |         null |    800000551111 |           8 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2072 |         null |    551260550909 |   exr531801 | 10.0.9.16
    1.9 |         null |    900000551111 |           9 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2092 |         null |    379419235555 |   exr993899 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2154 |         null |    916479555555 |   exr465158 | 10.0.9.16
'''
```

This is a python string as a table. I want the output like this :

```py
{{'1.1' : {'activation_code': '1000005-1212', 'account_guid': 'null',
  'external_id': '1', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}},
{'1.4.' : {'activation_code': '500000551212', 'account_guid': 'null',
  'external_id': '5', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}}.....}
```

Comment: "I have tried to convert string into list by split but I didn't get it." You did not get the string? You did not understand how to split a string? You did not get how to proceed?

Comment: "i want a logic."

Comment: @hardikgosai, *"i want a logic."* - that's a great desire ... and it's worth to make an effort ... try

Comment: i didn't understand how do do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 dbResponse = '''
 key    | account_guid | activation_code | external_id | location
--------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------
    1.1 |         null |    1000005-1212 |           1 | 10.0.9.16
    1.4 |         null |    500000551212 |           5 | 10.0.9.16
    1.6 |         null |    700000551212 |           7 | 10.0.9.16
    1.5 |         null |    400000551212 |           4 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1992 |         null |    157990235555 |   exr498680 | 10.0.9.16
'''

    split_str = dbResponse.split('\n')
    split_str = [s for s in split_str if len(s) > 0]
    strip_str = lambda x: x.strip()
    column = list(map(strip_str,split_str[0].split('|')))
    outresult = [] 
    for clm in split_str[2:]:
        outdict = {}
        out = {}
        splited_clm = clm.split("|")
        i = 1
        for c in column[1:]:
            out[c] = splited_clm[i]
            i = i + 1
        outdict[splited_clm[0]] = out
        outresult.append(outdict)
```

output

```
[{'    1.1 ': {'account_guid': '         null ',
   'activation_code': '    1000005-1212 ',
   'external_id': '           1 ',
   'location': ' 10.0.9.16'}},
 {'    1.4 ': {'account_guid': '         null ',
   'activation_code': '    500000551212 ',
   'external_id': '           5 ',
   'location': ' 10.0.9.16'}},
 {'    1.6 ': {'account_guid': '         null ',
   'activation_code': '    700000551212 ',
   'external_id': '           7 ',
   'location': ' 10.0.9.16'}},
 {'    1.5 ': {'account_guid': '         null ',
   'activation_code': '    400000551212 ',
   'external_id': '           4 ',
   'location': ' 10.0.9.16'}},
 {' 1.1992 ': {'account_guid': '         null ',
   'activation_code': '    157990235555 ',
   'external_id': '   exr498680 ',
   'location': ' 10.0.9.16'}}]
```

Hint:
1. Split the string into lines 
2. Split the lines into column

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```
import re
import pprint

db_response = '''
 key    | account_guid | activation_code | external_id | location
--------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------
    1.1 |         null |    1000005-1212 |           1 | 10.0.9.16
    1.4 |         null |    500000551212 |           5 | 10.0.9.16
    1.6 |         null |    700000551212 |           7 | 10.0.9.16
    1.5 |         null |    400000551212 |           4 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1992 |         null |    157990235555 |   exr498680 | 10.0.9.16
    1.3 |         null |    200000551212 |           2 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2052 |         null |    423838550909 |   exr084213 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2152 |         null |    563626550909 |   exr350970 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1534 |         null |    835749550909 |   exr245191 | 10.0.9.16
  1.161 |         null |    547489550909 |   exr413464 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1955 |         null |    961459478950 |   exr874895 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1812 |         null |    535999550909 |   exr991462 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2153 |         null |    525874550909 |   exr446117 | 10.0.9.16
    1.2 |         null |    300000551212 |           3 | 10.0.9.16
  1.206 |         null |    997141550909 |   exr987098 | 10.0.9.16
  1.101 |         null |    870827550909 |   exr867333 | 10.0.9.16
  1.302 |         null |    938271123405 |   exr989961 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1795 |         null |    360276365614 |   exr498651 | 10.0.9.16
  1.855 |         null |    751409654321 |   exr130325 | 10.0.9.16
 1.1232 |         null |    397846550909 |   exr557906 | 10.0.9.16
    1.8 |         null |    800000551111 |           8 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2072 |         null |    551260550909 |   exr531801 | 10.0.9.16
    1.9 |         null |    900000551111 |           9 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2092 |         null |    379419235555 |   exr993899 | 10.0.9.16
 1.2154 |         null |    916479555555 |   exr465158 | 10.0.9.16
'''

lines = [re.sub(r'\s+', '', line).split('|') for line in db_response.split('\n') if line and '-----' not in line]
head = lines[0]
result = {}
for line in lines[1:]:
    result[line[0]] = {col:line[no] for no, col in enumerate(head[1:])}
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
pawel@pawel-XPS-15-9570:~/test$ python parse.py 
{'1.1': {'account_guid': '1.1',
         'activation_code': 'null',
         'external_id': '1000005-1212',
         'location': '1'},
 '1.101': {'account_guid': '1.101',
           'activation_code': 'null',
           'external_id': '870827550909',
           'location': 'exr867333'},
 '1.1232': {'account_guid': '1.1232',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '397846550909',
            'location': 'exr557906'},
 '1.1534': {'account_guid': '1.1534',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '835749550909',
            'location': 'exr245191'},
 '1.161': {'account_guid': '1.161',
           'activation_code': 'null',
           'external_id': '547489550909',
           'location': 'exr413464'},
 '1.1795': {'account_guid': '1.1795',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '360276365614',
            'location': 'exr498651'},
 '1.1812': {'account_guid': '1.1812',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '535999550909',
            'location': 'exr991462'},
 '1.1955': {'account_guid': '1.1955',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '961459478950',
            'location': 'exr874895'},
 '1.1992': {'account_guid': '1.1992',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '157990235555',
            'location': 'exr498680'},
 '1.2': {'account_guid': '1.2',
         'activation_code': 'null',
         'external_id': '300000551212',
         'location': '3'},
 '1.2052': {'account_guid': '1.2052',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '423838550909',
            'location': 'exr084213'},
 '1.206': {'account_guid': '1.206',
           'activation_code': 'null',
           'external_id': '997141550909',
           'location': 'exr987098'},
 '1.2072': {'account_guid': '1.2072',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '551260550909',
            'location': 'exr531801'},
 '1.2092': {'account_guid': '1.2092',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '379419235555',
            'location': 'exr993899'},
 '1.2152': {'account_guid': '1.2152',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '563626550909',
            'location': 'exr350970'},
 '1.2153': {'account_guid': '1.2153',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '525874550909',
            'location': 'exr446117'},
 '1.2154': {'account_guid': '1.2154',
            'activation_code': 'null',
            'external_id': '916479555555',
            'location': 'exr465158'},
 '1.3': {'account_guid': '1.3',
         'activation_code': 'null',
         'external_id': '200000551212',
         'location': '2'},
 '1.302': {'account_guid': '1.302',
           'activation_code': 'null',
           'external_id': '938271123405',
           'location': 'exr989961'},
 '1.4': {'account_guid': '1.4',
         'activation_code': 'null',
         'external_id': '500000551212',
         'location': '5'},
 '1.5': {'account_guid': '1.5',
         'activation_code': 'null',
         'external_id': '400000551212',
         'location': '4'},
 '1.6': {'account_guid': '1.6',
         'activation_code': 'null',
         'external_id': '700000551212',
         'location': '7'},
 '1.8': {'account_guid': '1.8',
         'activation_code': 'null',
         'external_id': '800000551111',
         'location': '8'},
 '1.855': {'account_guid': '1.855',
           'activation_code': 'null',
           'external_id': '751409654321',
           'location': 'exr130325'},
 '1.9': {'account_guid': '1.9',
         'activation_code': 'null',
         'external_id': '900000551111',
         'location': '9'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split each new-line, next process the fields, then build the dictionary one row at a time.

**Note:** Removed the `dbResponse` declaration to eliminate any scrolling.

```py
import re

'''Converts a table to an object dictionary

Args:
    table     (string) : The table data
    key       (string) : The primary key
    delimiter (regex)  : An Optional delimiter used for splitting lines

Returns:
    result: A dictionary representation of the table, using the primary key
'''
def table_to_dict(table, key, delimiter='\s*\|\s*'):
  result = {}                                       # Initialize dictionary (object)
  lines = table.strip().split('\n')                 # Split new-lines 
  fields = re.split(delimiter, lines[0])            # The fields
  keyIndex = fields.index(key)                      # Index of the primary key
  for line in lines[2:]:                            # Start on the third line
    data = re.split(delimiter, line)                # Split each line
    result[data[keyIndex]] = {}                     # Create a new entry in the dictionary
    for i, value in enumerate(data):                # Enumerate over the values
      if i != keyIndex:                             # Do not store the key-value within the dictt
        result[data[keyIndex]][fields[i]] = value   # Set the value for they field in the entry of the dict
  return result                                     # Return the result

# Main entry function
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(table_to_dict(dbResponse, 'key'))           # Where `dbResponse` is the data above
```

#### Result

```py
{' 1.1': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '1000005-1212', 'external_id': '1', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.4': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '500000551212', 'external_id': '5', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.6': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '700000551212', 'external_id': '7', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.5': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '400000551212', 'external_id': '4', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.1992': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '157990235555', 'external_id': 'exr498680', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.3': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '200000551212', 'external_id': '2', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.2052': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '423838550909', 'external_id': 'exr084213', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.2152': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '563626550909', 'external_id': 'exr350970', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.1534': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '835749550909', 'external_id': 'exr245191', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.161': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '547489550909', 'external_id': 'exr413464', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.1955': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '961459478950', 'external_id': 'exr874895', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.1812': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '535999550909', 'external_id': 'exr991462', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.2153': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '525874550909', 'external_id': 'exr446117', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.2': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '300000551212', 'external_id': '3', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.206': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '997141550909', 'external_id': 'exr987098', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.101': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '870827550909', 'external_id': 'exr867333', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.302': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '938271123405', 'external_id': 'exr989961', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.1795': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '360276365614', 'external_id': 'exr498651', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.855': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '751409654321', 'external_id': 'exr130325', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.1232': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '397846550909', 'external_id': 'exr557906', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.8': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '800000551111', 'external_id': '8', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.2072': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '551260550909', 'external_id': 'exr531801', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.9': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '900000551111', 'external_id': '9', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.2092': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '379419235555', 'external_id': 'exr993899', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}, ' 1.2154': {'account_guid': 'null', 'activation_code': '916479555555', 'external_id': 'exr465158', 'location': '10.0.9.16'}}
```